# Particle System (Hair) - Rendered objects appears rotated/ off place

Tags: particles, hair

I was working on creating a grass plane and during the process of creating it, I made a plane on which the particle system was to be applied and an object - grass blade which is to be dispersed on the plane. I created a small number of varied grass blades and joined them. Upon choosing the group of grass blades ad the hair emission object of the plane, the result appears to be: the grass blades spawn half on one side and the other half on the other side (shown in the picture) and the grass blades sometimes seem to lay horizontally on the plane rather than vertically. The grass blades also overflow the borders of the plane as shown in the picture.

best,
Jassim
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the mesh you are using as hair, go to edit mode, and rotate / move till the floor emits the hairs in the correct position.

[image]